# Setting up a simple website with my own domain name on Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I have pretty much 0 experience in developing websites. I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction in setting up an Amazon EC2 instance with everything I need to make a simple website that will eventually have dynamic content (hence ec2).

Basically, I know that I may need something like nginx, that I will need to install Ruby (because I have already started playing around with it), etc. I just don't know what all I need to do ... I have a domain name, an Amazon EC2 account, but from there, I don't know where to go.

I've tried searching for tutorials like "amazon EC2 hello world website" and stuff like that, but I just can't find anything that would work for me.

Please let me know if you guys have any resources I can turn to ... or if you have a few simple steps (e.g. even if it is high level, that would be very appreciated: go to the getting started page for EC2, do those steps, install nginx by doing sudo apt-get blah blah blah).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've no experience in developing websites I wouldn't recommend starting off with EC2.  Working with EC2 adds a lot of extra steps and responsibilities that will tie up your time and effort without moving you any closer to focusing on your actual website or development.

I would recommend going to a managed hosting service that takes care of the server hardware and software  for you and lets you focus on working on your website.

You can find plenty of Ruby hosting solutions on http://www.railshosting.org/ and pick one that matches your interests.

- Dave

Comment: Hmm... thanks so much for your response, first of all! I was wondering if you could tell me what extra steps/responsibilities I may face -- and if those are 'worth it'

the other responder (Mr Jibaly) noted that I could go with something like Heroku. Would you recommend this one? Is it scalable? Other thing is, is it as reliable as EC2 ... ? I don't know anything about this company, whereas I'm confident Amazon will be around for a long time.

So with these solutions, do I just skip the steps of installing nginx, ruby, etc on a server ... and go directly to app dev or what? Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Ringo,I've never used Heroku. When running a site on EC2 you need to design with the assumption that various parts of the service may fail or restart.  It's a useful mentality to have for any host, but critical for EC2.  Some examples are that EC2 defaults to dynamic IP's, and that depending on your image type, you can't rely on content to be on the disk when you reboot.  There are ways around every limitation, but it's more planning and work than a managed solution.  I would recommend using a managed system until you outgrow it and the benefits start to become hindrances.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of guides out there, but if you just want to put up a hello world type of site up I'd recommend starting out on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/). It's free to get started and you can add a lot of advanced functionality with relative ease (compared to doing it on your own EC2 instance). It does run on EC2 behind the scenes, and allows you to use your own domain names.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!

So the main question I have now is, is Heroku good for scaling? I want to be able to have tons of views, etc for my site ... will Heroku be able to handle that easily?

Second thing, is having EC2 instance of my just an unnecessary complexity, or are there some real advantanges to having one? Thanks so much again for your help!!

Comment: Absolutely, Heroku is designed to scale (which is why it's built on top of EC2), and it's very simple to adjust the level (as well as the pricing).

Comment: You'd want your own instance if you find you need access to custom software (outside of the Rails stack and the SaaS Heroku provides access to). For example if you have a special Java executable that you had to integrate with your Rails application. Even then you'd scale much better if you created a web services interface to that custom app running on your EC2 instance and had your Heroku stack call it when needed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info! To clarify -- you're saying that if I wanted to run additional software, I could always have an EC2 instance and run it from there, and have my app on Heroku communicate with my app?

Comment: Precisely, this is especially useful since data transfer rates within the same EC2 region is free and within different regions is very cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my post "How to Setup a LAMP Server on Amazon EC2" - http://www.geekytidbits.com/setup-lamp-server-amazon-ec2/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.